# Refrigerated sugar cookie dough

Tags: baking

If my sugar cookie dough has been in the fridge for a few days how long should it sit out before I attempt to roll it out?

Comment: There's such a wide variety of sugar cookie recipes, and we don't know what shape/thickness you have it in the fridge. This is often a case of 'try it and see what happens'.  You can always cut a bit off, and try rolling just that bit out

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your sugar cookie dough is roughly like the one I make for cutting out cookies the be ideal and decorated: not very long.

A few minutes at room temperature should make it malleable enough to roll out this enough for cutting, and the process of working the dough with a rolling pin will warm it a bit more. The warmer the dough, the easier it is for the shapes to deform when moving to a baking sheet -- so you don't want to let it warm too much before you start to work with it.